# Log into a website and submit form data?

Tags: linux

I was wondering if it's possible to log into name.com and update a specific domains DNS from SSH? The VPS hostname is the domain I want modified.

I basically want to update each DNS field with the following

Log into `https://www.name.com/account/domain/details/$(hostname -i)#dns`

A Record `""` `$(hostname -i)`

A Record `"*"` `$(hostname -i)`

TXT `default._domainkey` `cat /etc/opendkim/keys/"$(hostname)"/default.txt`

TXT `""` `"v=spf1 mx a ip4:$(hostname -i) -all"`

I know they have an API (have to request signup as a reseller) but that is not an option for me.

Comment: Yes, by screenscraping. Have fun updating and reworking your scripts every time their website changes :)

Comment: I can't find any guides on screenscraping